# Salvar um objeto complexo com Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

O sistema possui uma tela de Pedidos onde pode-se adicionar itens novos ou alterar itens desse pedido.

O objeto que é enviado para a camada de Repositório é um objeto complexo `1 x N`, ou seja `Pedido` e `ItensDePedido`.

Minha dúvida é o seguinte: o Entity Framework sabe diferenciar um `Item Novo` de um `item Editado` ?

Explico melhor, veja o usuário acessa a tela de Pedido (faz novo pedido) e adiciona itens ao pedido e em seguida clica em Salvar e o sistema adiciona todos os itens ao Pedido, nesta situação nenhuma dúvida:

```
_repositorio.Pedidos.Add(_pedido);
_repositorio.SaveChanges();
```

O problema é quando o pedido é alterado, pois o usuário pode adicionar itens novos a esse pedido e como havia falado o objeto `_pedido` é um objeto complexo pode haver itens que já existem no banco de dados e itens que não existem.

```
_repositorio.Entry(_pedido).State = EntityState.Modified;
_repositorio.SaveChanges();
```

O Entity Framework deveria cuidar disso ? ou eu tenho que tratar isso no código ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Minha dúvida é o seguinte: o Entity Framework sabe diferenciar um Item
>   Novo de um item Editado ?

Se você criar um objeto *Pedidos* novo e anexar ele no contexto, o [Entity Framework](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework) saberá que esse objeto é um novo objeto e que deverár ser incluido no banco, isso é formalizado através da intrução 
`_repositorio.Pedidos.Add` e finalizado com o `_repositorio.SaveChanges();`

```
Pedidos _pedido = new Pedidos();
_repositorio.Pedidos.Add(_pedido);
_repositorio.SaveChanges();
```

Já quando você faz um `UPDATE` o contexto tem que saber qual objeto você esta alterado, para isso ele mapeia todas as propriedades do objeto no proxy, para isso uma consulta ao banco de dados deve ser realizada e mapeada 
para o contexto, um exemplo seria;

```
using (var ctx = new dbContext())
{
    var Pedido = ctx.Pedidos.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Pedido == 1);
    Pedido.Nome = "LCH .... ";
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Ou seja o `ctx.Pedidos.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Pedido == 1);` materializar o objeto no contexto, quando é chamado o `ctx.SaveChanges();`
uma query é montando com o `update` do campo `Nome`;

[Referencia 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb763516(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Referencia 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges(v=vs.113).aspx)

[Referencia 3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.submitchanges(v=vs.110).aspx)